# Does latin1 have performance benefits over utf8?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a table in `utf8` with > 80M records and one of the columns (`char(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL`) can contain just latin symbols (`[a-zA-Z0-9]`). Does it have the sense to convert this column into latin1?

MySQL [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) says:

> To save space with UTF-8, use VARCHAR instead of CHAR. Otherwise, MySQL must reserve three bytes for each character in a CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8 column because that is the maximum possible character length. For example, MySQL must reserve 30 bytes for a CHAR(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 column.

I made a test - created 2 tables with the same 50M records:

```
CREATE TABLE `t_utf8` (
  `c_1` char(6) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index_t_utf8_on_c_1` (`c_1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;

CREATE TABLE `t_lat` (
  `c_1` char(6) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `index_t_lat_on_c_1` (`c_1`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

but MySQL says that they have almost the same size:

```
           Name: t_lat
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 57557700
 Avg_row_length: 30
    Data_length: 1741668352
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 0
      Data_free: 2097152
 Auto_increment: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
 Create_options: row_format=COMPACT

           Name: t_utf8
         Engine: InnoDB
        Version: 10
     Row_format: Compact
           Rows: 57554528
 Avg_row_length: 31
    Data_length: 1810874368
Max_data_length: 0
   Index_length: 0
      Data_free: 3145728
 Auto_increment: NULL
      Collation: utf8_general_ci
 Create_options: row_format=COMPACT
```

Why does it so?

- MySQL 5.7
- InnoDB

P.S: I made the same test with MyISAM and got expected benefit: table with latin1 - 383Mb, utf8 - 1Gb. But why it does not work for InnoDB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:  Don't bother.

Long answer:

- https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=84440 -- you may or may not save space.
- InnoDB is inherently bigger than MyISAM.
- Comparing characters in utf8 is slightly slower than in latin1.  But you will probably not notice.
- The tiny difference between 1741668352 abd 1810874368 is probably due to the random nature of how you build one table from the other.  Or the phase of the moon, *not* something significant.
- The 30 vs 31 comes from how InnoDB estimates things.

Do not use `CHAR` except for truly fixed-length strings.  Almost always they are ascii, such as country_code, postal_code, UUID, hex, md5, etc.

Get in the habit of explicit saying ascii or utf8mb4 *when you create the column/table* unless you have an unusual case where you need something else.

Comment: Has `ascii` any advantages over `latin1` in this case? P.S.: `c_1 char(6)` contains random string from `[a-zA-Z0-9]` chars with constant length 6 (it's for shortener service like Google URL Shortener)

Comment: There are almost no differences between ascii and latin1.  For this alphanumeric case, you could use either one equally well.